# django render_to_response mimetypes

Tags: python, django, character-encoding

I have a string which instead of the byte `<27>` (hexadecimal) to represent `'` (apostrophe), uses the three bytes `<E2><80><99>`.  Firefox displays this as an apostrophe, but when passed through Django's `render_to_response` function, I get `â€™`.  Same goes for some other characters: `<E2><80><A6>` to represent `...` (elipsis) and `<E2><80><93>` instead of `-`.  Is there a name for this three-byte representation that Firefox seems to understand?

Where 'mydata' contains the string:

```
render_to_response(mytemplate, mydata, mycontext)
```

and

```
render_to_response(mytemplate, mydata, mycontext, mimetype='text/html')
```

works except for the funny characters

`render_to_response` has a `mimetype` parameter which I might be able to use if I know what the MIME type of my file is.  I have tried

```
render_to_response(mytemplate, mydata, mycontext, mimetype='application/xhtml+xml')
```

Which doesn't throw any exceptions it just never returns.

I have two questions: (1) What is the name of the character encoding my HTML file is using. (2) Will the `mimetype` parameter be able to help me render this the way I want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [UTF-8](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), which you should [decode to a `unicode`](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) before sending in a response.

Comment: It also doesn't work to write to a file opened in binary... Just trying to test it.

Comment: Your questions are answered in the second link.